# Calculating 2D Confidence Regions from MCMC Samples

Tags: confidence-interval, markov-chain-montecarlo, python

I would like to plot 2D confidence regions (at 1-sigma, 2-sigma) for a model that I've fit to data. I've used PyMC to generate 50k MCMC posterior samples for my model with 6 parameters.

I know the process to create confidence regions is something similar to:
1.) create a histogram of the samples in the 2D space
2.) identify iso-density contours
3.) from a selected start point (eg, the mean) integrate outwards perpendicular to iso-density contours until the desired fraction of sample points are contained in the region.

Is there a convenient function in the numpy/scipy/pymc/pylab/etc world that will create the 2D confidence region plot? Alternatively, where can I find a coded algorithm, or stand-alone tool, that will compute the contours for later plotting?

Answer (score 3):

I once did [something like this with pymc, matplotlib, and scipy](http://healthyalgorithms.com/2010/10/19/mcmc-in-python-how-to-stick-a-statistical-model-on-a-system-dynamics-model-in-pymc/) that you could adapt, the relevant code is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/626689#file-si_fit-py-L48-L68), and the resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Some type of description of the process would be very helpful....

Comment: The link provided has enough explanation as well as code.

Comment: In this solution the confidence levels of the different regions are not provided, e.g. the information about which region contains 95% of the samples is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

There is the R function `ci2d` from gplots that can create 2-dimensional empirical confidence regions: https://rdrr.io/cran/gplots/man/ci2d.html